# smartest way to create pivoted multi-index dataframe out of a stacked dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a very typical set of data that look like this:

```
data = {'date': {0: '10/02/2017',
  1: '10/02/2017',
  2: '10/02/2017',
  3: '10/02/2017',
  4: '10/02/2017'},
 'field': {0: 'field1', 1: 'field2', 2: 'field1', 3: 'field2', 4: 'field3'},
 'type': {0: 'type1', 1: 'type1', 2: 'type2', 3: 'type2', 4: 'type2'},
 'value': {0: 1.79067,
  1: 1.7987200000000001,
  2: 1.7978900000000002,
  3: 1.8001099999999999,
  4: 1.8045599999999999}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

this should look like this (real data set has many different dates):

```
        date   field   type    value
0 2017-10-02  field1  type1  1.79067
1 2017-10-02  field2  type1  1.79872
2 2017-10-02  field1  type2  1.79789
3 2017-10-02  field2  type2  1.80011
4 2017-10-02  field3  type2  1.80456
```

I want to create a pivoted multi-index dataframe such has:

```
              type1             type2                  
field        field1   field2   field1   field2   field3
date                                                   
2017-10-02  1.79067  1.79872  1.79789  1.80011  1.80456
```

the smartest way I found so far is this:

```
grouped = df.groupby('type')
res = {}
for name, df in grouped:
    res[name] = df.pivot(index='date', columns='field', values='value')
df = pd.concat(res, axis=1)
```

is there any other efficient way to achieve this?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1

By using `unstack`

```
In [36]: df.set_index(['date','field','type'])['value'].unstack([-1,-2])
Out[36]:
type          type1             type2
field        field1   field2   field1   field2   field3
date
2017-10-02  1.79067  1.79872  1.79789  1.80011  1.80456
```

---

Option2

`pivot_table`

```
pd.pivot_table(df,values='value',index='date',columns=['type','field'])
Out[464]: 
type          type1             type2                  
field        field1   field2   field1   field2   field3
date                                                   
2017-10-02  1.79067  1.79872  1.79789  1.80011  1.80456
```

Comment: did not know you could do that with pivot_table! thanks!

Comment: @StevenG glad it help ~ :)

Comment: So I tested for speed on a larger set of  and the unstack version is a bit faster (about 10%).

Comment: @StevenG you can test PiR 's `defaultdict` :) should be even faster

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**
Using `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))

for t in df.itertuples():
    d[('value', t.field, t.type)][t.date] = t.value

pd.DataFrame(d)

              value                                    
             field1            field2            field3
              type1    type2    type1    type2    type2
2017-10-02  1.79067  1.79789  1.79872  1.80011  1.80456
```

---

**Option 2**
Use `groupby`
This looks and feels a lot like @Wen's answer

```
df.groupby(['date', 'field', 'type']).first().unstack([-2, -1])

              value                                    
field        field1            field2            field3
type          type1    type2    type1    type2    type2
date                                                   
2017-10-02  1.79067  1.79789  1.79872  1.80011  1.80456
```

Comment: surprised by option 1 :-)

Comment: `defaultdict` ftw!

Answer (score 2):

```
(df
 .set_index('date')
 .groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('D'), 'field', 'type'])
 .sum()
 .unstack(['field', 'type']))
```

output:

```
              value                                    
field        field1            field2            field3
type          type1    type2    type1    type2    type2
date                                                   
2017-10-02  1.79067  1.79789  1.79872  1.80011  1.80456
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of set_index and unstack()

```
df1 = df.set_index(['date','field', 'type']).unstack().unstack().dropna(1).reset_index()
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel()
```

You get

```
type            type1           type2
field           field1  field2  field1  field2  field3
0   2017-10-02  1.79067 1.79872 1.79789 1.80011 1.80456
```

Comment: 4 sec different ~ LOL :)